# What does \@array mean in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

I have some Perl code where I noticed an array is used with a leading backslash like `\@array`

Can anybody explain what does it mean?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

the `\@` notation will return a reference (or pointer) to the array provided, so:

```
$arrayref = \@array
```

will make `$arrayref` a reference to `@array` - this is similar to using the `*p` pointer notation in C.

Comment: Please do not confuse pointers and references. `*(p + 3)` is perfectly valid in C (so long as `p` points to valid storage for at least 4 elements). What do you think `\@array + 3` is? First, you seem to think that pointers and arrays are the same in C, and, then,you are confusing C pointers with Perl references. Misleading.

Comment: It's good to add that using a reference to array as an array is this: `@{$arrayref}`

Answer (score 19):

It means it's a reference to an array.

[See the perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)  that explains it well

Answer (score -4):

Array references are primarily useful as parameters to subroutines. Without references, passing the array `@a` (with the elements 1,2,3) is pretty much the same as passing 1, 2, and 3 separately to the sub. With `\@array`, the sub can see the entire array, e.g. determine its length explicitly, manipulate it so that the caller can sees the changes, etc. The price for that power is that the sub has to use more complicated syntax when accessing the array elements: `$$a[0]` instead of `$a[0]`.

Comment: Subroutine arguments are always lists. If you do `func(@ary)`, the contents of `@ary` are passed as a flat list. Inside of `func`, you know how many arguments were passed (because the arguments are in `@_`). If you do `func(\@ary)`, then `func` receives a list consisting of a single argument. You can access the third element of the anonymous array to which the first argument to `func` refers using the standard arrow notation: `$_[0]->[2]`. Of course, you'd normally put that ref into its own variable as the first thing: `my ($ary) = @_; my $is_frobly = $ary->[2];` etc